# How to construct an image out of a vector of matrices using opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm in the process of splitting an image into areas of rectangles, i found some helpful code that allows me to do so, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to manipulate each individual area, and reconstructing them back together to form a new complete image of the same original size. I'm quite new to both c++ and opencv, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently, all rectangles are stored in an `std::vector<cv::Mat> *blocks`.

The reason I want the values of each rectangle, and be able to manipulate them, is because I plan to parse them to some output later on.

This is the code that splits the image up into rectangles:

```
    if(img.cols % colDivisor == 0 && img.rows % colDivisor == 0){
        for(int y = 0; y < img.cols; y += img.cols/colDivisor){
            for(int x = 0; x < img.rows; x += img.rows/rowDivisor){
                blocks->push_back(img(cv::Rect(y, x, (img.cols / colDivisor), (img.rows / rowDivisor))).clone());
                rectangle(maskImg, cv::Point(y,x), cv::Point(y + (maskImg.cols / colDivisor) - 1, x + (maskImg.rows / rowDivisor) - 1), CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1);
                cv::imshow("Image", maskImg);
```

I can manipulate the BGR values of a selected image like so:

```
    std::vector<cv::Mat> m;
    ...
    cv::Mat image2 =m[9]; //Random rect
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(image2, channels);
    cv::Scalar avg1 = cv::mean(channels[0]);
    cv::Scalar avg2 = cv::mean(channels[1]);
    cv::Scalar avg3 = cv::mean(channels[2]);
    std::cout << "Blue channel: " << avg1[0] << std::endl << "Green channel: " << avg2[0] << std::endl << "Red channel: " <<  avg3[0] << std::endl;
    image2.setTo(cv::Scalar(avg1[0], avg2[0], avg3[0]));
    cv::imshow("BGRTEST", image2);
```

As can be seen in the above code, I am successfully able to manipulate a single area, however, I want to iterate through each area and apply a mean BGR value to it.

How could I go about doing this?

I tried using a c++ iterator, like so:

```
for(std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator it = blocks->begin(); it != blocks->end(); ++it){

}
```

However, I'm not sure how I would implement such a thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the original task is to split the image into rectangular pieces and apply some operator on it, there is a simpler approach.

OpenCV has the rather convenient concept of a region of interest. You can select a region of an image and use that as an image. The operations you perform there will appear in the original image.

You are using a region of interest, but you copy it, and then plan to merge the small images you obtain. Not only this is wasteful in terms of computation, it also makes the code more complicated.

Here is how you can use the region of interest to your advantage:

```
for(int y = 0; y < img.cols - 30; y += 30) {
    for(int x = 0; x < img.rows - 30; x += 30) {
        cv::Mat roi = img(cv::Rect(y, x, 30, 30));
        std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
        cv::split(roi, channels);
        cv::Scalar avg1 = cv::mean(channels[0]);
        cv::Scalar avg2 = cv::mean(channels[1]);
        cv::Scalar avg3 = cv::mean(channels[2]);
        roi.setTo(cv::Scalar(avg1[0], avg2[0], avg3[0]));
    }
}
```

I have copied your processing and changed a bit the way the subimages are computed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Shame I didn't notice the ROI in the Mat documentation.. I already knew this was computationally expensive so I really hoped there would be some other approach. Thanks so much!